Do these new aliquot-based sequences grow forever?
In this question, I asked about a certain type of sequences that were based on aliquot sums merged with the $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ structure of Lucas and Fibonacci sequences. You can read about how I formulated those sequences in the question itself, but the basic idea is that the next item in the sequence is the sum of the aliquot sums of the previous two items. Now, it seems likely that many of those sequences trend to infinity, at least until they hit a number whose aliquot sum is odd (square numbers and their doubles, see my question here), of which the probability gets smaller as the numbers get higher. However, if you change the formula just slightly, you get sequences that grow much more slowly. Here's the recurrence relation (using $s(n)$ to denote the aliquot sum of $n$):
$$a_n = s(a_{n-1}) + s(a_{n-2}) + 1$$
The crucial difference is that "$+1$": in the other sequences, all the elements were fated to be even unless a square or its double was reached, the chance of which diminishes as your numbers grow. Even numbers, on average, will have larger aliquot sums than odd numbers (in fact, in my previous sequences, once an odd number was reached they started trending down); so while all the numbers are even the sequence will grow faster. These new sequences, however, follow the parity pattern "even, even, odd" (ignoring the exceptions of square numbers or their doubles), meaning that they grow more slowly. As an example, starting with $3$ and $4$ (a sequence that seemed to grow to infinity in my previous sequences):
$$3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3...$$
A better illustrator of the properties of these sequences, starting with $10$ and $12$:
$$10, 12, 25, 23, 8, 9, 12, 21, 28, 40, 79, 52, 48, 123, 122, 110, 171, 196, 293, 205, 49, 56, 73, 66, 80, 185, 150, 266, 437, 258, 314, 431, 162, 203, 239, 39, 19, 19, 3, 3, 3...$$
So far, the known loops that the sequences can end in are:
$$\{3 \to 3 \to 3...\}\{9 \to 9 \to 9...\}\{10 \to 10 \to 17 \to 10...\}\{24 \to 59 \to 38\to 24...\}\{78 \to 92 \to 167\to 78...\}$$
In addition, all of the loops will still loop upon reversal (ex. $38 \to 59 \to 24 \to 38...$).
My question, though, is not about these loops; it is about sequences such as the one starting with $2$ and $12$. Here are the first few numbers in the sequence:
$${\scriptsize 2, 12, 18, 38, 44, 63, 82, 86, 91, 68, 80, 165, 230, 326, 369, 344, 494, 663, 692, 872, 1305, 1814, 1946, 2325, 3058, 3626, 4855, 3850, 6056, 10393, 5882, 4082, 6069, 6310, 8822, 10717, 7190, 7310, 12717, 13348, 17246, 19471, 8628, 11534, 17759, 9588, 17966, 25703, 11100, 21886, 33983, 14116, 12612, 27439, 18062, 12748, 21099, 18822, 28088, 43427, 24594, 24608, 48509, 24354, 36578, 54419, 18294, 18308, 33599, 15294, 15308, 27719, 12990, 18836, 34451, 16974, 23120, 56321, 37314, 49058, 74189, 28464, 45194, 69119, 23928, 35954, 53933, 22896, 48980, 102605, 79068, 143060, 293969, 194064, 370196, 659453, 311886, 363908, 636845, 469854, 1040342, 1400021, 756606, 989390, 1580909, 935262, 1252694, 1735313, 626352, 991850, 1874879, 1062312, 1772810, 3279419, 2761032, 5456510, 8746595, 8030424, 16203014, 20697011, 8159196, 10878958, 16318439, 5448124, 4961566, 7433711, 2653708, 2180486, 3905159, 1961676, 3234806, 4806479, 1648260, 3364514, 5034269, 1764852, 2504972, 4314305, 2754792, 5569166, 8740493, 4034196, 6163448, 13305599, 7163490, 10291064, 22219943, 12661602, 13373000, 31412135, 26671986, 44292824, 75127595, 53781762, 68807300, 134286533...}$$
The sequence grows -- you can see that it went from a two-digit number to an nine-digit number -- but it grows quite slowly, slower than my previous sequences. Other combinations follow similar patterns (for example, starting with $(4, 12)$, $(12,8)$, or $(999,1000)$). So, my goal:

Prove that either there is some sequence that must grow to infinity, or that all sequences will eventually result in a loop.

Thanks for your help!
